# Answer not accepted for codewards --- but my output matches their desired output

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, automated-tests, integration-testing

This is the kata:

From https://www.codewars.com/kata/5264d2b162488dc400000001/train/python

> Write a function that takes in a string of one or more words, and returns the same string, but with all five or more letter words reversed (Just like the name of this Kata). Strings passed in will consist of only letters and spaces. Spaces will be included only when more than one word is present.
>
> Examples: `spinWords( "Hey fellow warriors" )` => returns `"Hey wollef sroirraw"` `spinWords( "This is a test")` => returns `"This is a test"` `spinWords( "This is another test" )`=> returns `"This is rehtona test"`

This is my code:

```
def spin_words(sentence):
    sentence_array = sentence.split()
    new_array = []
    for word in sentence_array:
        if len(word) >=  5:
            word = word[::-1]
            new_array.append(word)
        else:
            new_array.append(word)
    new_sentence = ''
    for word in new_array:
        new_sentence += word + ' '
    
    return new_sentence
```

Having trouble figuring out why it isn't being accepted

Comment: Hint: Take a look at the last character of your output strings! You might be adding something to the end that was not intended...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing additional space at the end which is wrong.

```
def spin_words(sentence):
    sentence_array = sentence.split()
    new_array = []
    for word in sentence_array:
        if len(word) >=  5:
            word = word[::-1]
            new_array.append(word)
        else:
            new_array.append(word)
    
    return ' '.join(new_array)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that the returned strings will have a trailing whitespace. Remove them by using a slice of `[:-1]`:

```
def spin_words(sentence):
    sentence_array = sentence.split()
    new_array = []
    for word in sentence_array:
        if len(word) >=  5:
            word = word[::-1]
            new_array.append(word)
        else:
            new_array.append(word)
    new_sentence = ''
    for word in new_array:
        new_sentence += word + ' '
    
    return new_sentence[:-1]
```

For a cleaner and more efficient approach:

```
def spin_words(sentence):
    word_array = sentence.split()
    spin_array = [word[::-1] if len(word) > 4 else word for word in word_array]
    new_sentence = ' '.join(spin_array)
    return new_sentence
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to get it to pass:

```
def spin_words(sentence):
sentence = "Hey fellow warriors"
sentence_array = sentence.split()
new_array = []
for word in sentence_array:
    if len(word) >=  5:
        word = word[::-1]
        new_array.append(word)
    else:
        new_array.append(word)
print(new_array)
new_sentence = ' '.join(new_array)
print(new_sentence)
return new_sentence
```